How to adjust and center font text based on available space
I am currently writing a program that prints certificates when a course is completed. The certificates are in .png format and I am using Pandas to read the name of the person from an Excel spreadsheet and then write the name on the .png image certificate.
The issue I have is with the length of the names of some students and I want my program to be able to adjust the font size to fit the name of the student in the space provided automatically.
I have the coordinates of where to start writing the text (in pixels) and where the text should end on the .png image. Ideally I would like to:

start writing the name of the student from the middle so the alignment of the name is also in the middle
adjust the font size of the name for the space

Can anyone advise the best way to go about this?
Example code:
 im = Image.open("C:\\Documents\\Certificate\\Effort.png")
 d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
 Start_location = (553, 3023)
 d.text(Start_location, "Test User")

The above code starts right where I have specified (which is from the left side of the A4 paper) but it is not aligned in the center so there is a lot of space to the right, especially if the name is short.

Take a look at the documentation here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text. This gives examples of how to align the text at the centre point, and how to measure the text. Given the size of the text you can then adjust the font to make it lareger or smaller.

I tried it with the following code, and that worked. I downloaded the font from BeFonts, the empty certificate from Activity Shelter, and generated names using Behind the Name.
import os.path

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from PIL.ImageFont import FreeTypeFont

CUR_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(CUR_DIR))
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data', 'stack_overflow')
PATH_TO_EMPTY_CERTIFICATE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'certificate.png')

MAX_WIDTH = 1000  # Hardcoded value to fit comfortably on the certificate
SIGNING_Y = 590  # Hardcoded value to place it just above the line


def name_to_code(name: str) -> str:
    result = ''.join([c.lower() if c.isalnum() else '_' for c in name])
    while '__' in result:
        result = result.replace('__', '_')
    return result.strip('_')


def sign_certificate(name: str):
    # Load the empty certificate and the font
    img = Image.open(PATH_TO_EMPTY_CERTIFICATE)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font_file = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'fonts', 'cs-verity-font-1722652677-0',
                             'CSVerity-Regular_demo-BF66ab0975c331d.otf')

    # Define the correct font size for the text to fit on the certificate
    font_size = 73
    text_width = 1E9  # A very large number, to ensure we enter the while-loop below
    text_bbox: tuple[float, float, float, float] = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    font: FreeTypeFont | None = None
    print(f'Trying to fit {name} on the certificate...')
    while text_width > MAX_WIDTH:
        font_size -= 1
        font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file, font_size)
        text_bbox = font.getbbox(name)
        text_width = text_bbox[2] - text_bbox[0]
        print('Font size:', font_size, 'Text width:', text_width)
    text_height = text_bbox[3] - text_bbox[1]

    # Calculate the position of the text
    x = (img.width - text_width) / 2
    y = SIGNING_Y - text_height

    # Draw the text on the image
    draw.text((x, y), name, font=font, fill='black')

    # Save the signed certificate
    code = name_to_code(name)
    output_file = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, f'certificate_{code}.png')
    img.save(output_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sign_certificate('Chione Reva')
    sign_certificate('Bora Ramadevi Bernadett Gizella Mac an Ghoill')




